# export file as .msh in blender 2.8

Tags: mesh, export

I want to know how to create a .msh file in blender. What is the best solution to do that in blender 2.8?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please ask only one question at a time, make as many posts as necessary. You should edit your question to focus on a single issue.

Comment: Well they are very related in my opinion, because they are two different solutions  to the same problem but I'll remove the solution that i tried in that case.

Comment: I misread your question, but yes unless related you should post things separately. About the error message it should probably be reported to the addon author, not much we can do about it here.